# Trim and remove number function and add to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I took some code from W3Schools and edited it to remove numbers and trim leading and trailing whitespace. That works as expected and I’m happy with how it removes spaces and numbers.

I tried `var str = myTrim(#input-q5);` but was unable to get it working. not sure how to proceed.

```js
function myTrim(x) {
  return x.replace(/\d+|^\s+|\s+$/g, '').trim();
}

function myFunction() {
  var str = myTrim("7987 iuiuh 98798");
  
  alert(str);
  $(str).val($('#input-q6').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input-q5" Value="345 King Street">
<input type="text" id="input-q6">
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="test">Try it</button>
```

Comment: `var str = myTrim(#input-q5);` isn’t valid JavaScript. What exactly is the problem? In your original code, where did the additional `}` at the end come from? Consider learning from more reputable sources, like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn), instead of sites like W3Schools that will still teach programmers to use `onclick` attributes in 2018.

Comment: The last line of your JS shouldn't exist, there is no bracket to close

Comment: The problem is that **element $('#input-q6') has NO value** in HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a working snippet, first get the value and store it in `val` then assign it using the same function!

```js
function myTrim(x) {
  return x.replace(/\d+|^\s+|\s+$/g, '').trim();
}

function myFunction() {
  var val = $('#input-q5').val();
  var str = myTrim(val);
  $('#input-q6').val(str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input-q5" Value="345 King Street">
<input type="text" id="input-q6">
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="test">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This:

```
function myTrim(x) {
return x.replace(/\d+|^\s+|\s+$/g,'').trim();
}

function myFunction() {
var str = myTrim($('#input-q5').val());
alert(str);
}
```

Comment: [“Try this” answers are not useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811/4642212). Please add some explanation.